# I have to show $(B+I)^2=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let D be a division ring and $n≥3$. assume that $charD=2$ and $B \in M_n(D)$ is a non-scalar involution matrix. I have to show $(B+I)^2=0$.I know a matrix $T \in M_n(D)$ is called an involution if $T^2=I$.

Comment: In a division ring of char $2$, we have $(B+I)^2 = B^2 + B + B + I^2 = I + I$

Comment: The fact that @avash is poor at maths does not justify the donwvote, in my opinion.

Comment: @AlexM. [This pattern of "questions"](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/224527/avash?tab=questions&sort=newest) justifies all the downvotes.